# MySQL convert between two date format

Tags: mysql, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

The user will enter the date in this format : 17-Feb-2017

and the date stored in mysql db is in this format : 2015-02-17 00:00:00

what I tried to do is

```
SELECT * FROM insurance where DATE_FORMAT(in_date,'%d-%b-%Y') > '17-Feb-2017';
```

DATE_FORMAT(in_date,'%d-%b-%Y') return the date in this format : 17-Feb-2017

but that not working !!

any suggestions ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp Follow this link it will help you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the input to a date type and the column value too:

```
SELECT * FROM insurance where date(in_date) > STR_TO_DATE('17-Feb-2017','%d-%b-%Y')
```

For more explanation about `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE` function see the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).
Do not convert both values to string, because you can not compare it after the convertion